# Django Slug unique in categorie

Tags: django, listview, slug, django-class-based-views, detailview

I am trying to come up with a URL definition in Django to support this

/categories/categorie_slug/products/product_slug

Where categorie_slug is Unique, and product_slug is unique for the parent categorie.

My views:

```
"""
Listviews
"""
class CategorieList(ListView):
    context_object_name = "categorie_list"
    model = Categorie
    queryset = Categorie.objects.order_by('-created_at')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(CategorieList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all Products
        context['product_list'] = Product.objects.all()
        return context


class ProductList(ListView):
    context_object_name = "product_list"
    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
        categorie = self.kwargs['categorie']
        return Product.objects.filter(categorie=categorie)

"""
Detailviews
"""
class CategorieDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "categorie"
    model = Categorie

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super(CategorieDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        categorie = self.object
        # Add in a QuerySet of all posts for the given estimates
        context['product_list'] = Product.objects.filter(categorie=categorie)
        return context


class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    context_object_name = "product"
    model = Product
```

My URL patterns:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', login_required(CategorieList.as_view()),name="categories"),
    url(r'^.*categories/$', login_required(CategorieList.as_view()),name="categories"),
    url(r'^.*categories/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(CategorieDetail.as_view()), name='categorie'),

    url(r'^.*categories/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/products/$', login_required(Productlist.as_view()), name="products"),
    url(r'^.*categories/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/products/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', login_required(ProductDetail.as_view()), name="product"),
)
```

The problem is that I have to add the categorie-slug as second argument to my Productdetail, as both slugs make a product unique.

Comment: Why don't you use [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#unique-together) ?

Comment: The Product-Slugs are unique in a category. From my Product Model:
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique_with='Categorie__slug')

Comment: unique_together = ('slug', 'categorie__title',)